# django-forms: allow logged in user to submit only one comment per individual post

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-validation

I have a model Post in which the User can leave a Comment along with a set of ratings. I would like to limit the user comments to only one per post. I'm having trouble setting that up in my view

models

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="usernamee")
    ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

class Post(models.Model):
...
```

views

```
def add_comment(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

# I tried wrapping all of the below in an "if" statement, something like
# if request.user.comment.exists(): to check if the user has already
# left a comment on this specific post, but I'm not sure of the right way to perform such a check here.

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post 
                comment.user = request.user 
                comment.email = request.user.email
                comment.picture = request.user.profile.profile_image_url()

                comment.save()

                messages.success(request, "Thank you for leaving a review!")
                return redirect('blog:post_detail', slug=post.slug)

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Something went wrong! We weren't able to process your review :(")  
        else:
            form = CommentForm()



        template = "blog/post/add_comment.html"
        context = {

            'form': form,
            'post': post,
            #'comment_count': comment_count

            }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

I am under the impression that all I would need is to wrap the entire form code from my add_comment view in some sort of validation system that checks whether or not the current, logged-in user has already left a comment on that specific post (see comments in view)

Anybody know what a potential solution might be? Or if I'm even doing this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be to:

1. Get the current `Post` comments in view
2. Filter the comments by your `request.user`
3. See if the query returned a non-empty queryset

Something like:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


def add_comment(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    # Get the comments posted by the user for this post
    user_comments = post.comments.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

            # Check if there are any comments posted by the user
            if user_comments:
                # If there are any, raise an error
                raise PermissionDenied('You have already commented on this post.') 

            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post 
                comment.user = request.user 
                comment.email = request.user.email
                comment.picture = request.user.profile.profile_image_url()

                comment.save()

                messages.success(request, "Thank you for leaving a review!")
                return redirect('blog:post_detail', slug=post.slug)

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Something went wrong! We weren't able to process your review :(")  
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    template = "blog/post/add_comment.html"
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'post': post
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Of course, you can modify the error raising here, but the main idea is to get the comments and filter them by `request.user` and see if there are any.

Comment: Thanks a ton! All I needed was the 'user_comments = post.comments.filter(user=request.user)'. I wrapped my whole form request in that if statement, so that if the user has already left a review, then it won't even let them access the add_comment form page. It's so easy when thinking about it, but for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to get the info about whether the user has commented or not. Thanks again!!